# Intermittent Ambiguous Column Error in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a complex stored procedure that will also call other stored procedures as part of the workflow.  I have checked all stored procedures for the **ambiguous column 'ColumnId'** error.

The first oddity is that the error is paramaterized with a single input and the error will not recreate for all users even with the same input.  The second oddity is that I have checked all the SELECT, JOIN, WHERE, ORDER BY, and GROUP BY for the normal errors of ambiguity and not found any violations.

The only potential violation might be

```
SELECT      RateID
FROM        Rate.tblRate
INNER JOIN  #tmpRate
ON          tblRate.CustomerID = #tmpRate.CustomerID
```

Could the line for ON be an issue as it is not

```
ON Rate.tblRate.CustomerID = #tmpRate.CustomerID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the proc could return different, or multiple result sets making this behavior sporadic. However,I've seen this for temp tables a lot, though I can't explain why. If you alias that table, it resolves it every time.

```
SELECT      RateID
FROM        Rate.tblRate r
INNER JOIN  #tmpRate t
ON          r.CustomerID = t.CustomerID
```

This is good practice as it is required for other instances, like table variables.
if object_id('tempdb..#temp') is not null drop table #temp

```
select 1 as ID into #temp

declare @table table (ID int)
insert into @table
values
(1)

select * 
from
@table 
inner join #temp on #temp.ID = @table.ID
```

This will throw the error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@table".

So, alias it and it will work:

```
select * 
from
@table t
inner join #temp on #temp.ID = t.ID
```

There are a lot of blogs out there on why it's a good habit to pick up. [Here is one.](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/04/using-aliases-in-multi-table-queries/)

Comment: I believe this will likely be the answer but I have to monitor for another week or so to see if it disappears from Elmah report.  Thank you for the advice.

Comment: No sweat at all @DMadden51